# Block Quick Look During Downtime

Tags: finder, pdf, system-settings, quicklook, screen-time

According to System Preferences, the Downtime feature of Screen Time "[s]ets a schedule for time away from the screen. During downtime, only apps that you choose to allow and phone calls will be available." Downtime blocks most apps, but it does not block Finder. It blocks the Quick Look feature of Finder for video but not audio or PDF. How can I block Quick Look for all file types during downtime? Alternatively, can I force a log out during downtime? As I recall, the Restrictions feature that preceded Screen Time could force a log out. If Screen Time cannot do this, then what parental control apps can?

Comment: Parental Controls? Forced Log-out? Can you explain what you are trying to achieve, and then we can suggest the best way to  go about it.

Comment: @benwiggy Thank you for your comment on my question. How can I force a logout during downtime?

Comment: I mean: what's your goal by doing this? Are you trying to stop a child from using the computer entirely, at specific times?

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, I am trying to lock the computer entirely at specific times.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using software like Qustodio, which will do exactly what you want.

There's no native way to force a log out between certain periods.

Technically, you can do it manually with plist launch items set at intervals between the log out and log in times, but this is fraught.

Notably, the MacOs downtime feature has bugs, anyway. For instance, if the computer rolls over into downtime whilst Paramount Plus is playing in full screen mode, command tabbing out of full screen, then clicking on Chrome in the dock will bring the fullscreen video back up in viewable form.

Try Qustodio.